# Is Aviary a Flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, user-interface

I wonder if www.aviary.com web applications are builded using flex framework. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't access aviary.com right now (some DNS problem) but if you can get to the SWF then you can put it into my "Is it Flex?" tool:
http://www.jamesward.com/is_it_flex/

That uses a tool called swfdump (part of the open source Flex SDK) to read the compiler metadata out of the SWF.

Comment: Yup! http://www.jamesward.com/is%5Fit%5Fflex/?url=http%3A%2F%2Faviary.com%2Fapps%2Fflash%2Faviary%2Fphoenix.swf

Comment: this tools does not seem to work correctly. It triggers Flex for some pages that made of ActionScript only.

Comment: Hi Hippo.  It says it's Flex if it was compiled with Flex.  It doesn't factor in whether the Flex Framework was used.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at View Source in the Aviary.com Phoenix flash web-app shows that it does use  FLEX API. I cannot say for sure if it was built with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Flex application, 100% positive.